My app RERUNS from the beginning every time I enter a message in an st.chat_input(). How can I prevent the rerun from happening?
I have a simple chat bot application with a simple chat interface.
import streamlit as st

# Function to handle when some text is entered into the chat_input() by the user
def handle_chat_input():
    # setting session state variables
    st.session_state.human_input = st.session_state.user_input
    st.session_state.topic = st.session_state.user_input
    st.session_state.generating = True
    st.session_state.asking = False

# Function to render the st.chat_input()
def render_chat_message():
        human_input = st.chat_input("Type your message here...", key="user_input", on_submit=handle_chat_input)

render_chat_message()

Chatbot Code Logic:
Somewhere in the backend of my Chatbot, I have a code logic which waits for the
st.session_state.asking 
to be set to False by the chat_input(). And then the code logic gets the human input from the st.session_state.human_input and prompts the LLM with it and proceeds with the execution. This is how the LLM get the input prompt from the user.
@tool
def ask_human_input_tool(question_for_human: str) -> str:
    """This tool is used for asking a human input. This tool takes a question as an input and ask the input.
        The tool return a the answer received."""
    st.session_state.asking = True
    
    # Wait for st.session_state.asking == False
    while st.session_state.asking
        print(st.session_state)
        time.sleep(7)

    human_input = st.session_state.human_message
    return human_input

But the PROBLEM is every time I hit enter or submit the text in the chat_input(), my whole application runs again from the beginning. Now I understand that any time something must be updated on the screen, Streamlit reruns your entire Python script from top to bottom.
My Question
Because of this my chatbot executes and runs from the beginning, which I want to prevent from happening. How do I prevent the app rerun every time I interact with the widget? Is there a a concrete way to just disable the rerun?
Note: Should I not be using a while loop to wait for the session state to update? is there a better way to do it?

This is what I have tried:

I wrapped the the render_chat_input() function with a @st.experimental_fragment as shown below:

# Function to render the st.chat_input()
@st.experimental_fragment
def render_chat_message():
        human_input = st.chat_input("Type your message here...", key="user_input", on_submit=handle_chat_input)

Now with this fragment rendered. The issue is that any interaction I have with this widget only updates this particular fragment. What I mean specifically by this is that when the session state state is changed in this fragment, it is not visible outside of this fragment. This is preventing my code logic from seeing the updates/changes made to the session state in the chat_input().

I have also tried putting a st.text_input() in an st.form() as an alternative but the human input tool doesn't see it too.

Or maybe I am using it wrong Can I see some example code for how it is implemented in a st.form()?
